# Using two Jquery slideshows on one page

Tags: jquery

Im new to using Jquery. I know there are lots of different questions on this same subject but none of the advice seems to help. Can someone help me out with the code please.

Here is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="P1js/jquery.rs.slideshow.js"></script>
  <script src="L1js/jquery.rs.slideshow.js"></script>

  <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.rs-slideshowP1').rsfSlideshow();
                });

                $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.rs-slideshowL1').rsfSlideshow();
                });
                </script>

</head>
<body>



      <div id="slideshowP1" class="rs-slideshowP1">
            <div class="slide-containerP1">
                <img src="P1images/0.jpg" />

            </div>
            <ol class="slidesP1">
                <li>
                    <a href="P1images/0.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="P1images/1.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="P1images/2.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="P1images/3.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="P1images/4.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="P1images/5.jpg"></a>
                </li>
            </ol>

    </div>


<div id="slideshowL1" class="rs-slideshowL1">
            <div class="slide-containerL1">
                <img src="L1images/1.jpg" />

            </div>
            <ol class="slidesL1">
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/1.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/2.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/3.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/4.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/5.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/6.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/7.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/8.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/9.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/10.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/11.jpg"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="L1images/12.jpg"></a>
                </li>
            </ol>

 </div>
```

Id really appreciate anyones help who can set me straight. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you only need to include the slideshow.js once, however that shouldn't have caused problems. What problems are you having with the code you provided?

Answer (score 0):

Although I cant understand the problem you are facing, but this might help you..

```
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                   $('.rs-slideshowP1').rsfSlideshow();
                });

                var j=jQuery.noConflict();

                j(document).ready(function () {
                   j('.rs-slideshowL1').rsfSlideshow();
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just refer them by their unique identifier (i.e) by their id. If you are still facing issues, tell us what exactly is the error message you are getting